# PHP static method init $_SESSION var?

Tags: php, session, static-methods

I found strange feature with $_SESSION var

```
class A
{
    static function doSomething()
    {
        $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
    }
}

A::doSomething();

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

As you may guess session is not started but $_SESSION var is initialized. Who can explain what actually happens?

Comment: What's the output? What did you expect? What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

$_SESSION is a superglobal, so it's accessible without the necessity of `session_start()` having been called.

Also, you don't need to initialize the $_SESSION array

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

to use it like any other array

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$_SESSION` is a [superglobal array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php):

> By default, all of the superglobals are available...

So you can always access this array. This would also work when there was no POST Request, but you could do `$_POST['foo'] = 'bar'`.

When you try to go to another page in your example, where you don't call A::doSomething, you will see, that `echo $_SESSION['foo'];` will throw an error, since you didn't call `session_start();`.

Comment: $_SESSION is undefined by default. I didn't call session_start in this code! It's a whole code.

Comment: Even though `_SESSION` is undefined by default, you can still write to the variable as a superglobal.  It is the php session module that keeps these values between requests (i.e. `session_start()`)